# register_chrdev function arguments in linux device driver

Tags: linux-device-driver

Why pointer to file_operation structure is required in funcion **register_chrdev** as argument?How is the structure used by this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in character device you will read/write data in streams of data, for user the device is just a file (device node), whenever he wants to read/write data to the device, he will use the device file and he will update, hence when user does read/write, your driver should provide these basic file operation's implementation.

register_chrdev along with allocating major and minor number, it registers the specific file operations for the device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the data in the chrdev. You can do this via a file-like interface. This is why you use `struct file_operations`: to give the kernel information about what needs to be done for reading the chrdev for example.

Fact is, `register_chrdev` does a lot more than only registering a major for the device. If you want to only register a major and a minor you should use `register_chrdev_region`.